# Performance cost when using custom hooks to detect element height React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The common problem of having a `position: fixed` header and applying consistent padding to the content below it so that nothing is covered. If the content inside of the header is dynamically subject to changing and the styling needs to stay consistent regardless of what is added or removed.

I implemented this hook:

```
export const useElemHeight = () => {
  const elementRef = useRef(null);
  const [heightOfEl, setHeightOfEl] = useState(null);

  function handleCheckElHeightOnScreenResize() {
    setHeightOfEl(elementRef.current.clientHeight);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (elementRef.current) {
      setHeightOfEl(elementRef.current.clientHeight);
      window.addEventListener("resize", handleCheckElHeightOnScreenResize);

      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("resize", handleCheckElHeightOnScreenResize);
      };
    }
  }, [elementRef]);

  return [elementRef, heightOfEl];
};
```

**Application**

```
export default function App() {
  const [elementRef, heightOfEl] = useElemHeight();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header ref={elementRef} />
      <Content height={heightOfEl} />
    </div>
  );
}

const Content = ({ height }) => {
  const ADDITIONAL_UNITS = 20;

  return (
    <div
      className="content"
      style={{ paddingTop: `${height + ADDITIONAL_UNITS}px` }}
    >
      CONTENT
    </div>
  );
};

export default Content;
```

regardless of what content is added or removed from the header the padding will always stay consistent via all screen sizes, but are there any real performance costs to implementing something like this? Working demo here.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-smoke-2h8e7h?resolutionWidth=670&resolutionHeight=924&file=/components/Content.jsx:0-238)

Comment: There's nothing frequent or expensive, so no

Comment: @CertainPerformance what about frequency of potential resize events?

Comment: That'll probably happen very infrequently, right? The user is not likely to resize the window more than once or twice on a single page, if even that, I'd think

Comment: You can use a `throttle` or `debounce` to make sure that it doesn't lag while resizing

Comment: @KonradLinkowski is it possible get an implementation?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/throttle-debounce